# Drupal site setting `Content-Type` to `application/x-gzip` all the time

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal, bluehost

I am in the process of migrating an existing Drupal website from another provider to Bluehost.com -- while I think using Bluehost.com is not relevant in this context I thought I'd mention it anyway, in case there are indeed some particularities I'm not aware of.

The site is a Drupal 6 installation and it did work previously I am told on bluehost too so you think it shouldn't be any problems, however, having copied it over I encounter a big problem: all the responses from Drupal are sent with `Content-Encoding` set to `application/x-gzip`. This has the implication of all browser presenting a download dialog box rather than rendering the content.

I have actually curl'd the index page and ran it through gunzip and the output is the correct HTML for the site -- just that it somehow ends up being gzip'd and this mangles the content type and confuses the browsers.

Talking to previous maintainers of the site they suggested using PHP 5.4 (they were running it on php 5.5 as I understand and despite all the Drupal suggestions it was running perfectly well I'm told).

I am trying to eliminate now any type of gzip'ing that occurs here so I've got it down to a few layers which could cause it but eliminating those it still doesn't work:

- `SetEnv no-gzip 1` in `.htaccess`
- `zlib.output_compression = Off` in `php.ini`
- drupal had the `boost` module installed and some corresponding settings in `.htaccess` -- i've removed those from the `.htaccess` file as well as deleting the `boost` directory from `sites/all/modules`

The problem still stands and my files are being sent to the browser compressed. Is there any other way to disable this?

Note that this only happens for pages inside Drupal, having uploaded a simple php page and navigate to that url works fine -- which suggests therefore a drupal (rather than apache/php) problem.

I've noticed a module `mimedetect` which has a definition for `application/x-gzip` in there but not sure how could this affect it as removing this didn't render anything useful either.

Any ideas where to look and/or what might cause it?

Happy to provide any other insights that might be useful in diagnosing this.

Comment: How did you upload the Drupal files on your bluehost account? Can you confirm the permissions of files & directory? There should never be an issue with uploading files to any hosting account unless bluehost has some special requirements.

Comment: All permissions set correctly.  I have uploaded via ftp.

Comment: Try this way: Zip all the files, upload to your hosting account and they unzip them there.

Comment: It's not a file permission issue, as I said all the php code executes there's no errors anywhere in logs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so having actually reset the database cache and with the settings above this now works. I'm trying to figure out which one of the above actually solved it.